# Gluon position service is taking too long to display the coordinates

Tags: gps, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I tried the following code, it's working, but making the first click on the button after launching the app, the message with the coordinates show right when the button is clicked, but for the next clicks, the message takes long time unfortunately to display the message.

My code is as follows:

```
button.setOnAction(e->{
        PositionService positionService = Services.get(PositionService.class).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("PositionService not available."));
        positionService.positionProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Latest known GPS coordinates from device: " + nv.getLatitude() + ", " + nv.getLongitude()));
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters you shouldn't add a new listener to the position service every time you click the button. You have to do it just once, maybe after clicking the button once or in the view initialization.

Comment: I also tried like this - `MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Latest known GPS coordinates from device: " + positionService.getPosition().getLatitude() + ", " + positionService.getPosition().getLongitude());` but it didn't work.

Comment: As I said above, initialize the service and add the listener just once, outside the button event handler, with the view initialization.

Comment: Sir, I couldn't understand. Can u please give me a link of some example, which I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a single view project created with the Gluon plugin for your IDE, and you have added the required `location` service and the permission to the Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In the `BasicView` you can do for instance:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    Label label = new Label("GPS is not active");

    Button button = new Button("Active GPS");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LOCATION_ON));

    button.setOnAction(e -> {
        Services.get(PositionService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            // if there is GPS service, disable button to avoid adding more
            // listeners
            button.setDisable(true);
            label.setText("Waiting for GPS signal");

            service.positionProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> 
                label.setText("Latest known GPS coordinates:\n" + nv.getLatitude() + ", " + nv.getLongitude()));
        });
    });

    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    setCenter(controls);
}
```

Or you can initialize the service when you create the view, without the need to activate it:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    Label label = new Label("GPS is not active");

    Services.get(PositionService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
            label.setText("Waiting for GPS signal");

            service.positionProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> 
                label.setText("Latest known GPS coordinates:\n" + nv.getLatitude() + ", " + nv.getLongitude()));
        });
```

}

Either way, you can deploy the app to your Android/iOS device and test.

**EDIT**

Optionally, if you want to include a button, so you can click on it as many time as you want.

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    Label label = new Label("GPS is not active");

    Button button = new Button("Get GPS coordinates");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LOCATION_ON));
    button.setDisable(true);

    Services.get(PositionService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
        label.setText("Waiting for GPS signal");

        service.positionProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
            label.setText("Latest known GPS coordinates:\n" + nv.getLatitude() + ", " + nv.getLongitude());
        });

        // enable button and add listener to retrieve coordinates
        button.setDisable(false); 
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            Position position = service.getPosition();
            MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Latest known GPS coordinates from device:\n" + 
                    position.getLatitude() + ", " + position.getLongitude());
        });
    });

    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    setCenter(controls);
}
```

Note that when clicking the button you should use `service.getPosition()`.

Comment: Sir, this is not what I was looking for. I was actually looking for the solution, once I click on the button, the position will be displayed in a message box, like `MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("...")` and I can click on the button as many times as I want.

Comment: In my code snippet I've shown _how_ it can be done, but you can adapt it as you need to. Changing `label.setText()` to `showMessage` for instance.
I'll edit my answer to add a way to click on the button as many times as you want.

Comment: Done, check it and _modify it_ as you will.

Comment: So, the trick was keeping the button action inside the position property listener!

Now I hope, I can create a thread to read and send the device location in a server once the location updates! :) 

Thanks a ton, sir! :)

Comment: That's not what I've done. Check again. The position listener is added just _once_. The button listener is also added just _once_. The position listener receives the updates from the device, while the button listener asks for the current position to the device on user's demand. If you plan to add a thread you just need the position listener, and whenever you receive an update, you will process that to your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :). I have checked! ^_^